# How to get all data from an Android app in a computer?

Tags: android, adb

I've got on my tablet an app in Arabic from which I would like to extract the data. To do that, I used `adb backup com.my.app`, and then opened the .ab file with android-build-extractor. I've got some data in pdf format, however I didn't get the totality  (I've got ~1300 pages, but the total content is ~5000 pages). Can someone explain me what happened and how to fix it ? I'm on Ubuntu, but I can use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

> adb pull  com.my.app

Comment: I'm gonna try. Thx.